# Find and replace in nested objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, multidimensional-array

I'm struggling with the following issue:

I have a nested object. From the server I get a response with an object with changed values. So I want to find the object in my nested object and replace it.

My object has a structure like this:

```
$scope.page = {
  id: 5,
  label: 'myPage',
  items : [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "id": 1,
      "label": "header",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Container",
          "id": 2,
          "label": "left",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Menu",
              "label": "settings-menu",
              "id": "5"
            },
            {
              "type": "Menu",
              "label": "main-menu",
              "id": "7"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Container",
          "id": 4,
          "label": "right",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Post",
              "label": "contact",
              "id": "25"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Postlist",
      "label": "nieuwsberichten",
      "id": "17"
    },
    {
      "type": "HTML",
      "label": "over deze site",
      "id": "18"
    },
    {
      "type": "Other",
      "label": "twitter feed",
      "id": "19"
    }
  ]
}
```

From the server I get a new object:

```
var newItem = {
  "type": "Post",
  "label": "contact",
  "id": "25"
}
```

How can I update the object inside $scope.page the right way? I've tried the following:

```
$scope.findAndReplace(newItem,$scope.page.items);

$scope.findAndReplace = function(newItem, items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].id == newItem.id) {
      items[i] = newItem;
    } else if (items[i].items) {
      $scope.findAndReplace(newItem, items[i].items);
    }
  }
}
```

and:

```
var oldItem = $scope.findById(item.id, $scope.page.items);
oldItem = newItem;

$scope.findById = function(id, items) {
  var match = null;
  angular.forEach(items, function(i){
    if (match == null) {
      if (i.id == id) {
        match = i;
      } else if (i.items) {
         match = $scope.findById(id, i.items)
      }
    }
  })
  return match;
}
```

Neither of these options work. That's because of the nested loops where the object isn't the one in $scope.page anymore.

Anyone an idea to handle this?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: You're right. I thought it was a specific issue for angular, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks fine, can't understand why they are not working.

> Neither of these options work. That's because of the nested loops where the object isn't the one in $scope.page anymore.

You can keep object reference by using `angular.copy(newItem, oldItem)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have created a fiddle for you.
[click for fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satyendon/wvpaav4k/6/)

```
    for(var indx=0; indx < $scope.page.items.length; indx++) {
    var tmpObj = $scope.page.items[indx];
  if(tmpObj.hasOwnProperty('items')) {
    // check inside
    for(var indx1=0; indx1<tmpObj.items.length; indx1++ ) {
        var innerObj = tmpObj.items[indx1];
      // check for next level
      if(innerObj.hasOwnProperty('items')) {
        for(var counter=0; counter< innerObj.items.length; counter++) {
            var thirdTmp = innerObj.items[counter];
            console.log('3rd level inner object', thirdTmp);
          if(thirdTmp.id === newItem.id) {
            innerObj.items[counter] = newItem;
            tmpObj.items[indx1] = innerObj;
            $scope.page.items[indx] = tmpObj;
          }
        }
      }

    }
  } else if(tmpObj.id === newItem.id) {
    $scope.page.items[indx] = newItem;
  }
};
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, please do not forget to accept the answer and upvote .. good luck :)

Comment: I want to search recursive. In your example you have to write the loop over and over again, as often as your object is deep. So if my object is 10 levels deep I have to put 10 loops inside the functoim